# Does Virus affected Node Modules transfer in Contents of SPFx deployment package

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, anti-virus

When we scaffold an SPFx webpart/Extension we get many Node Modules as part of dependencies. These can be seen in `node_modules` folder and there are also entries in `package-lock.json` file.

I know these are dependencies for development.

Now assume a case where one of the Node Modules contains Virus (like in flatmap-stream and event-stream). Does the package files generated from commands `gulp bundle --ship` and `gulp package-solution --ship` will contain any of the code from all or effected Node Modules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TLDR;**

The short answer is no, the package doesn't contain all of the code from node_modules, yet it contains some very small amount of proven code (mostly css-loader code from corresponding webpack loader).

**Long answer**

SharePoint Framework uses webpack to bundle your code into a single file (aka package). Apart your code SharePoint Framework contains a lot of components which you reference in your code via imports (`import smth from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base'` etc.), however, those components are not included in your code. They serve as "externals" and are loaded by SharePoint Framework at runtime.
If you take a look at webpack configuration, you will see below picture:

```
   ....
devtool: 'source-map',
      entry:
       { 'hello-world-web-part':
          'C:\\temp\\spfx-test\\lib\\webparts\\helloWorld\\HelloWorldWebPart.js',
         'my-new-wp-web-part':
          'C:\\temp\\spfx-test\\lib\\webparts\\myNewWp\\MyNewWpWebPart.js' },
      externals:
       [ '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset',
         '@microsoft/sp-core-library',
         '@microsoft/decorators',
         '@microsoft/office-ui-fabric-react-bundle',
         '@microsoft/sp-diagnostics',
         '@microsoft/sp-dynamic-data',
         '@microsoft/sp-polyfills',
         '@microsoft/sp-http',
         '@microsoft/sp-page-context',
         '@microsoft/sp-loader',
         '@microsoft/sp-component-base',
         '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base',
         '@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core',
         '@microsoft/sp-extension-base',
         '@microsoft/sp-application-base',
         '@microsoft/sp-client-preview',
         '@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench',
         'react',
         'react-dom',
         'HelloWorldWebPartStrings',
         'MyNewWpWebPartStrings' ],
      output: 
....
```

Everything which is in the external section won't be included into the resulting bundle, yet it will be served at runtime by Microsoft. Your package contains only your code (plus a bit of code from webpack's css-loader like mentioned earlier). You can run `gulp clean` then `gulp bundle` and open `./dist` folder to review the generated bundle. Only your code will be included.
Which basically means that you shouldn't care about such things like viruses, etc. However, Microsoft should care that all externals modules they use (aka `@microsoft/*` and `react*`) are virus-free and safe.
From your side, you should only care about any external modules you install **after** scaffolding your project. For example react modules, or helpers, or whatever else.

**Additional reading:**

[250+ vulnerabilities in a new SharePoint Framework project](https://rencore.com/blog/250-vulnerabilities-sharepoint-framework/)
[Don't be alarmed by vulnerabilities after running NPM Install](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/don-t-be-alarmed-by-vulnerabilities-after-running-npm-install)
[Code Security Audit using “npm audit”](https://www.helloitsliam.com/2018/11/03/code-security-audit-using-npm-audit/)

Comment: There is the possibility that the `webpack` or one of it plugins has "evil" code in and injects this into your build result  (like in [XcodeGhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XcodeGhost)). But the size and importance makes likely that such an attack would be detect fast

Comment: That's true, but this is the task for Microsoft, because like mentioned all webpack modules as well as node modules with dependencies are externals and controlled by Microsoft. So technically "evil" code won't be in your bundle unless you add it explicitly.